# Null pointer exception in getWritableDatabase();

Tags: android, exception, android-context

In my app I am using dbhelper class, insertion into the db works fine and I can access the table contents, the problem is when I call the insertion method for the second time from another activity am getting null pointer exception in `getWritableDatabase()`. can someone help me in fixing this bug?

Comment: code snippet would be better.

Comment: post your code, please

Comment: Can you post your code you're working on now ?

Comment: If your issue is resolved, accept the answer that was correct or just put an answer and accept it, so that, it helps developer looking for correct answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be second time , you are opening the DB as getreadable and not closing that.I did this mistake in past and got the above error.